# Method that fetch data from multiple databases running slow

Tags: c#, sql, algorithm, linq, linq-to-sql

I have some method that needs to fetch statistics data from multiple databases. The key idea is that each table hold a DBName and from it I drill down to the Client Main DB calling a stored proc with the desired database name. finally I drill down a second time to get data from the client's Project Database.

To sum it up:

1. I get the list of all my cloud users.
2. For each User I fetch his Clients by using stored proc on his main DB -> Marked as userClients.
3. For each Client I fetch his Statistic by using stored proc on the Clients Project DB.

It takes about 5-6 secs to execute for very little data.

```
public List<CloudAnalysisDTO> GetCloudAnalysisForPeriod(DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate)
    {
        var users = FindAll();
        List<CloudAnalysisDTO> resultsList = new List<CloudAnalysisDTO>();
        HashSet<string> userclients = new HashSet<string>();

        using (var db = new ProjSQLDataContext(conn))
        {
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                if (user.ID == 0)
                    continue;

                var ids = string.Join(",", db.UserClients.Where(uc => uc.UserId == user.ID).Select(uc => uc.ClientId.ToString()).ToArray());
                var mainDB = user.MainDB;

                if (mainDB.Length == 0 || ids.Length == 0)
                    continue;

                List<CloudAnalysisDTO> userClients =
                        db.ExecuteQuery<CloudAnalysisDTO>(@"EXEC CloudUsersAnalysis {0},{1}", mainDB, ids).ToList<CloudAnalysisDTO>();

                List<CloudAnalysisDTO> needRemove = new List<CloudAnalysisDTO>();

                foreach (var client in userClients)
                {
                    if (!userclients.Contains(user.MainDB + client.ClientID.ToString()))
                        userclients.Add(user.MainDB + client.ClientID.ToString());
                    else
                    {
                        needRemove.Add(client);
                        continue;
                    }

                    ClientAnalysisDTO clientAnalysisDTO =
                    db.ExecuteQuery<ClientAnalysisDTO>(@"EXEC CloudClientAnalysis {0},{1},{2}", client.ProjectDB, FromDate, ToDate).SingleOrDefault<ClientAnalysisDTO>();

                    if (clientAnalysisDTO != null)
                    {
                        client.ClientAnalysisDTO = clientAnalysisDTO;
                    }

                    client.UserID = user.ID;
                    client.MainDB = user.MainDB;
                }

                foreach (var removeDTO in needRemove)
                {
                    userClients.Remove(removeDTO);
                }

                if (userClients != null && userClients.Count > 0)
                    resultsList.AddRange(userClients);
            }



        }
        return resultsList;
    }
```

Any ideas of what I can do to improve performance ?

Comment: Looks like a lot of db calls to me.

Comment: To me aswell, but is there any other way ? I don't know enough sql tricks to pull it off. Maybe what the database admins do is caching the statistics in some intervals but I have not even slight idea of how to do that.

Comment: You pull statistics into .NET and do the looping in .NET.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that's what I'm doing now.

Comment: Not you are not.  You are looping calls to DB.  That is NOT the same as getting all the information you need in one DB call and then looping in .NET collections.

Comment: But how would I get ALL the information in my situation with one DB call? that's actually the question. Saying what I should without giving a concrete example/idea is not really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: It is a comment.  How is it not helpful if you did not even know that is not what you are doing now?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is enable .NET tracing, and write a line to the tracelog before and after each call.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6s4h68(v=vs.110).aspx

This line makes me suspicious that you might be secretly running an "in" clause in one of the queries, which might be less-than performant:

```
 var ids = string.Join(",", db.UserClients.Where(uc => uc.UserId == user.ID).Select(uc => uc.ClientId.ToString()).ToArray());
```

The next step once you find the weak performer (the above line is just my guess), you should enable database profiling to determine where there needs to be new indexing or database maintenance.

Comment: I do use an "in" clause in my first sproc! what I can do instead is create a loop and fetch the Users Clients 1 by 1 from .Net with regular where. but I don't think that's the reason for it to run that much slower. And it would mean calling the sproc even more times.

Comment: You could reference each database in a JOIN statement in something like a view or a single stored proc. You just refer to databasename.schema.table, eg: "myDB.dbo.myTable". Putting it into a single procedure would let the server handle the optimization. (it looks like you're on a single server instance, if I'm wrong you'll need to add a linked server). Other than that, make sure you're referencing indexed fields in anything that you join.

Comment: I would not know how to do that cause each User row has a different mainDB column. and the join needs to be on that column's value. So Join [this is value]->(mainDB).dbo.myTable ON (What goes here?)